# When extending a Trait should every method be implemented?

Tags: scala

In this code below the class StockGrabber is not causing a compiler error. 
Since StockGrabber is extending Subject should its methods not be implemented ? :

`

```
object Observer extends Application{

  trait Subject {
      def register(o : Observer)
      def unregister(o : Observer)
      def notifyObserver
  }

  trait Observer{
      def update(ibmPrice : Double , aaplPrice : Double , googPrice : Double)
  }

  class StockGrabber extends Subject{



  }
}
```

`

Comment: The code doesn't compile for me : `error:  class StockGrabber needs to be abstract, since it has 3 unimplemented members : ...`.  What version are you running ?

Comment: @Marth thanks for checking. the issue for me was that there was a another class on my build path which was not compiling. This seems to cause issue in question. I'm using Eclipse Juno with Scala 3.0.0